# How to calculate twist and wrench in local and global frames

Tags: robotic-arm, jacobian, geometry, screw-theory

I am rather new to screw theory and also lost in robotics books' formulas. we have a simulator of a robot arm within Mujoco physics engine and I'm wondering how I can calculate wrench and twist in the local and base coordinate frame.

In the simulator what I have available is the end-effector's translational (jacp) and rotational(jacr) Jacobians. In addition I can obtain joins positions, velocities, accelerations and torque sensors' readings along with some other time dependent variables that are usually available in simulators.

Comment: What are you hoping to calculate the wrench and twist of? The end effector? Each link? What would you consider to be the "local" and "base" frames? Unfortunately, it's hard to answer your question without more specifics.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* azerila, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.